# Printing from a windows service on Windows Server 2012

Tags: c#, windows, printing, windows-services, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a windows service in C# .NET 4.6.1 that is building SSRS reports and sending the report to various network printers. All printers are installed locally on the server where the service is installed. All this was working on a Windows Server 2008R2 server and recently the client upgraded to Windows Server 2012R2 and now no printouts. I am getting no errors and when checking the job status on the printer I can see the job count on the printer increase by 1 and the PrintJobStatus.Spooling is true but nothing comes out on the printer.

```
            private bool PrintSheet(AppPrintRequest model, PackagingEntities db)
            {
                try
                {                                                
                    var oPrinter = db.AppPrinters.Where(x => x.AppPrinterID == model.AppPrinterID).FirstOrDefault();

                    var lpsPrintServer = new LocalPrintServer();
                    var psPrintServer = new PrintServer();
                    var sbLog = new StringBuilder();

                    byte[] reportBytes = BuildSSRSReport(model);

                    PrintQueueCollection pqcAvailablePrinters;

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(oPrinter.AppPrinterServer))
                    {
                        pqcAvailablePrinters = lpsPrintServer.GetPrintQueues();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        pqcAvailablePrinters = psPrintServer.GetPrintQueues();
                    }

                    sbLog.AppendFormat("System: {0} ", model.AppPrintRequestSystem);
                    sbLog.AppendFormat("Printer: {0} ", oPrinter.AppPrinterAddress);

                    foreach(var oAvailablePrinter in pqcAvailablePrinters)
                    {
                        sbLog.AppendFormat("Printer FullName: {0} ", oAvailablePrinter.FullName);
                        sbLog.AppendFormat("Printer Name: {0} ", oAvailablePrinter.Name);
                        sbLog.AppendFormat("Printer Description: {0} ", oAvailablePrinter.Description);
                    }

                    var oLaserPrinter = pqcAvailablePrinters.FirstOrDefault(pqCurrent => pqCurrent.Name.ToUpper() == oPrinter.AppPrinterAddress.ToUpper());

                    sbLog.AppendFormat("Report Bytes is null = {0} ", reportBytes == null);
                    sbLog.AppendFormat("Laser Print is null = {0} ", oLaserPrinter == null);

                    if (reportBytes != null && oLaserPrinter != null)
                    {
                        sbLog.AppendFormat("Report Bytes Length: {0} ", reportBytes.Length);
                        sbLog.AppendFormat("Laser Printer: {0} ", oLaserPrinter.Name);
                        sbLog.AppendFormat("Laser Printer Busy: {0} ", oLaserPrinter.IsBusy);

                        PrintSystemJobInfo oPrintJob = oLaserPrinter.AddJob();                                                            

                        sbLog.AppendFormat("Laser Printer Job Count: {0} ", oLaserPrinter.NumberOfJobs);                    

                        GetPrintJobStatus(oPrintJob, sbLog);

                        oPrintJob.JobStream.Write(reportBytes, 0, reportBytes.Length);
                        oPrintJob.JobStream.Close();

                        oPrintJob.Refresh();

                        sbLog.AppendFormat("Job Completed: {0} ", oPrintJob.IsCompleted);

                        NLogger.Debug(string.Format("Print Sheet: {0}", sbLog.ToString()));

                        return true;
                    }

                    NLogger.Debug(string.Format("Print Sheet: {0}", sbLog.ToString()));

                    return false;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    NLogger.Fatal("PrintEngine_PrintSheet", ex);

                    return false;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Ignoring your service for the moment, can you print a test page from Windows to the printers?

Comment: @Matt yes, I am able to print test pages to the printers successfully